Big O notation of T(n) = T(n/2) + O(log n) using master theorem?
I am aware that the algorithm has 1 recursive call of size n/2 and the non-recursive part takes O(log n) time.
Master theorem formula is T(n) = aT(n/b) + O(n^d). In this case a = 1, b = 2, but I am not sure what d is because it is formatted as O(log n), not O(n^d).

You check very carefully whether you can apply the master theorem in this case at all.
Or you just note that T(n) is just the sum of O(log 2^k) for 1 <= k < log n, which equals O(log^2 n).
In general, T(n) = T(n-1)+f(n) is just the sum of f(k) for 0 <= k < n, and for T(n) = T(n/2) + f(n) you just substitute n = 2^n’ then use the same formula.

It looks like there's a "fourth condition" to the master theorem, which indeed allows me to use it: https://cse.unl.edu/~choueiry/S06-235/files/MasterTheorem.pdf
